# Lando links to local site are red

Tags: docker, nginx, lando

working on an existing project that was working on my Win 10 machine. and continues to work on a Colleagues mac

calling

```
lando start -vvv
```

launches docker, starts the containers
but where it check the urls for the site lando prints  `checking to see if https://localhost:52144 is ready. diversiview 14:53:11 DEBUG ==> scan failed for https://localhost:52144 code=undefined, message=Request failed with status code 502, status=502, server=nginx, date=Wed, 09 Nov 2022 03:53:11 GMT, content-type=text/html, content-length=150, connection=close diversiview 14:53:11 DEBUG ==> Response for https://localhost:52144, returned http code we should retry for. Setting to bad`

and the nginx docker container prints  `2022/11/09 03:52:58 [error] 238#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.20.0.6:9000", host: "diversiview.lndo.site"`

tried on a new computer and the same problem meaning something has changed in the project but
ive tride backups of the project from when it was working and they dont anymore.
tried with docker using WSL and without.

I dont know enough about lando or docker to know what other info to provide

re installed all programs relevent

Comment: In my computer caused by Brave VPN